# Ваш запрос не содержит указанное выражение, как часть агрегатной функции

Tags: sql, ms-access

Не получается рассчитать стоимость с учетом скидки

```
SELECT зТоварный_чек.[Номер товарного чека], 
зТоварный_чек.[Дата продажи], Sum(зТоварный_чек.Сумма) AS Стоимость,
 IIf(Sum([Сумма])>2000,Sum([Сумма])*0.05,0) AS [Сумма скидки],
 [Сумма]-(IIf(Sum([Сумма])>2000,Sum([Сумма])*0.05,0)) AS [Стоимость с учетом скидки]

FROM зТоварный_чек

GROUP BY зТоварный_чек.[Номер товарного чека], зТоварный_чек.[Дата продажи];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Сумма]-(IIf(Sum([Сумма])>2000,Sum([Сумма])*0.05,0)) AS [Стоимость с учетом скидки]
^^^^^^^ этого поля нет в group by и оно не аггрегировано
```

`[Сумма]` отсутствует в `group by`, вы не можете её использовать в выборке. Вот `Sum([Сумма]` - можете, потому что это аггрегирование по всей группе.

Если вы хотите получить стоимость с учётом скидки именно по всему чеку, то просто поставьте `Sum` там где вы её пропустили, и всё:

```
Sum([Сумма])-(IIf(Sum([Сумма])>2000,Sum([Сумма])*0.05,0)) AS [Стоимость с учетом скидки]
^^^ - вот тут пропущено было Sum
```

Comment: Гениально, огромное вам спасибо!